# Update React Hook after axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, state

I think I'm not far from solution, but I'm stuck right now.

Here is my component with a button that delete a row in a mongoDB collection :

```
Object.entries(userWalletIncomes).map(([key, value]) => {
                        return (
                            <div id="incomeTable" className="text-left mx-auto flex" key={key}>
                                <p className="w-32 border p-1 capitalize">{key} :</p>
                                <p className="w-32 border p-1 text-green-500">{value}€</p>
                                <button onClick={(e) => handleDeleteIncome(key)}><i className="fas fa-times text-gray-400 text-xs p-1"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
```

And here is my function that make the axios request, and `then`, set the new state with the hook :

```
const handleDeleteIncome = (key) => {
        let data = { [key]: "" }
        axios({
            method: "delete",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/balanceOneIncome/${uid}`,
            data: data
        })
            .then(() => setUserWalletIncomes(userWalletIncomes))
    }
```

Problem is, I have to reload the page to see the new state. I would like to avoid reloading pages

Any idea ?

Comment: In a react way, you have to reset the list, so cannot avoid the reloading of the page. Try to give every row a unique id to avoid every row refresh.

Answer (score 2):

.then functions need a callback, you are currently just calling setUserWallerIncomes() in it instead of passing that as callback like so:

```
    .then((res) => {
         console.log(res.data) // do something with the response data
        setUserWalletIncomes(res.data) // not sure what your response type is but that's probably what you're looking for
     })
```

Edit: userWalletIncomes is an object so changed setState to take object

Comment: Thanks for help. But the same error pop with this code 

Comment: Error : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): userWalletIncomes is not iterable

Comment: you are also trying to set state but using spread operator? maybe you were instead trying to do something like my edit  setUserWalletIncomes([...userWalletIncomes, res.data]). Dunno what your response code is though.

Comment: Oh, if userWallerIncomes is an object, do  setUserWalletIncomes({...userWalletIncomes, ...res.data}) instead

Comment: ok so this code create something strange lol. It create one line for each letter of the response. x)

Comment: Maybe irrelevant but whenever you use your state object like this be sure to use a functional state update so you are updating from the previous state versus whatever state is closed over in the callback, i.e. `setUserWalletIncomes(userWalletIncomes => [...userWalletIncomes, res.data]);`

Comment: What is your initial state? 

const [userWalletIncomes, setUserWallerIncomes] = useState("What is inside here??");

Comment: try removing ... from res.data, that should give you what you want I think, can't really tell for sure unless I know what response data you're getting

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code made me change my post, now it works but I have to reload page

Comment: Ok, you're just setting state to the same value with             .then(() => setUserWalletIncomes(userWalletIncomes)). You must use the response data in your axios.then and setUserWalletIncomes according to your response data and needs